# Dialogflow fulfillment fetch not showing response

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

When I call the intent `llamada` the intent webhook triggers but it doesn't appear what I pass in the `agent.add(json[0].name)`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const fetch = require('node-fetch')

let url = (ommited)
let settings = {method: "Get"};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.post('/webhook', express.json() ,function (req, res) {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request:req, response:res }); 
 
  function llamada(agent) {
    fetch (url, settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      agent.add(json[0].name)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise error'); 
    });
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('llamada', llamada);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
})
 
app.listen(3000, () => {
});
```

[image: Dialogflow not showing the agent.add(json[0].name)]

I get this error:

```
ok
(node:9936) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE
    at V2Agent.sendResponses_ (C:\Users\aasensio\Desktop\Zerca\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\v2-agent.js:243:13)
    at WebhookClient.send_ (C:\Users\aasensio\Desktop\Zerca\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js:505:17)
    at C:\Users\aasensio\Desktop\Zerca\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js:316:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9936) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with 
.catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9936) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can I make it to get in Dialogflow the response correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're doing an asynchronous operation with a Promise, but `agent.handleRequest()` doesn't know to wait for the Promise to complete. So it tries to return a result to Dialogflow immediately, but the result hasn't been set yet.

In your case, addressing this is straightforward. You just need to return the Promise that is generated by the `fetch().then()...` chain. Something like this should work:

```
    return fetch (url, settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      agent.add(json[0].name)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise error'); 
    });
```